# How to create and change ownership of a directory from within a Docker container

Tags: python, django, linux, docker

I have a Django app with an api endpoint for creating a directory for a user. When receiving the request, the app runs `subprocess.check_output` to create a directory for the user in an NFS mount and then run `chown` so that only that user has the proper permissions to add files to the directory.

Now, I'm trying to migrate the app to run inside a Docker container but need to retain this functionality. What is the best way to do this? I've thought of having a volume to the NFS mount in the host machine but I'm not sure if that works, specially since the user wouldn't exist inside the Docker container and hence chown would fail. Something else I thought was having a shell script which can be called from the Docker container and run in the host machine but I don't know if that's possible

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.